# How to use .filter inside ReactJs Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

I'm Using React for the first time and I am trying to filter a JSON response so that I can display a list of products.

When I log the result of the filter to the console I seem to get the correct data. However when I try and map over it and render it ".Products" seems to be undefined.

[image]

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { MenuContext } from '../context/menuContext';

function Category() {
    const [categoryItems] = useContext(MenuContext);

    const category = categoryItems.filter(element => element.CategoryName == "Rice");

    console.log(category);

    return (

        <div>
            <h1>Category Page</h1>

            {category.Products.map(productItem => (
                <h3 key={productItem.Id}>{productItem.ProductName}</h3>

            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
export default Category;
```

Update: Thanks @Ori Drori for your comment. I have tried to use .find and still does not work.

I think this is something to do with how react works. Becuase in the console I am getting an empty output before I get the correct result.

Update 2: I implemented the answer that I have marked as correct and its now working. HOWEVER. There are two things I don't understand and I would like someone to explain.

1. When I call

console.log(console.log(category);

Why is it that in the console I see 'undefined' before I get the result with the data.

[image]

2. Why do I need to put 'category &&' when I remove it. It stops working.

Comment: `Array.filter()` returns an array of items, so the the `Products` are actually under. `category[0].Products`. Use `Array.find()` instead of a filter, because it returns only a single item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`category` is a list, not a single object. The output of an `Array.filter` is always a list. That is why: `category.Product` is `undefined`.

If you want to find a category with the name `Rice`, you can change the code to:

```js
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { MenuContext } from "../context/menuContext";

function Category() {
  const [categoryItems] = useContext(MenuContext);

  const category = categoryItems.find(
    (element) => element.CategoryName === "Rice",
  ); // change `filter` to `find` and `==` to `===`

  console.log(category);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Category Page</h1>

      {category && // add this because category can be undefined
        category.Products.map((productItem) => (
          <h3 key={productItem.Id}>{productItem.ProductName}</h3>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
export default Category;
```

If it still does not work, show the error and also console.log category.Products

Answer (score 1):

When you used the method filter it returns as an array:

```
category.map(()=>)
```

or use the method to find the item product in category:

```
const find = category.find(elem=>elem.product)
find.map(()=>)
```